# how to prove curl (fv)

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

How to prove this?
$$\nabla\times(\varphi\mathbf{F}) = \nabla\varphi\times\mathbf{F} + \varphi\nabla\times\mathbf{F}.$$

$\varphi$ is a scalar valued function and $F$ is a vector field.

Comment: Let ${\bf F}=(F_1,F_2,F_3)$ then work out the left hand side and right hand side.  If you need more help than this, please post your working and explain where you are stuck.